# CSS styles disappear after refresh in React app

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm at a loss when it comes to figuring out why this is happening. Right now my hunch is that this is a Webpack issue. I don't have this refresh problem on the dev environment, but only when I build and run that code.

Basically, when I'm on certain pages, and I refresh the app ... all the styles I have in a stylesheet are being ignored, and when I check the response it is actually just showing my index.html page.

[image: Network Response]

I am importing the styles into the root of my app, so in the index.js. I know it is still going through that on refresh cause that's where my persistedState logic is happening, and what allows the refresh to work.

Here is my webpack config for production environment. I feel like that has to be the problem somewhat, since the dev environment is just fine. Unless I'm not thinking of other potential problems?

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
};

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css?sourceMap")},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file"},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
  }
};
```

Would love anyones thoughts or solutions to this problem!

**EDIT:**

Here is the webpack dev config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    //'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file"},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
  }

};
```

Head tag of HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500|Work+Sans:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/6.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  </head>
```

Comment: What does your development webpack config look like? BTW this is most likely a problem with the http server. Whatever is in charge of serving your application files is sending you the root page (index.html) instead of your style.css.

Comment: @Raspo yeah! I'll edit that into my question real quick ... one sec.

Comment: @Raspo it's up now.

Comment: I can see a different loader being used for css in production

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are using a relative path to the CSS file in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

When you visit `/example/page/` you're trying to request `/example/page/styles.css`, but as that doesn't exist, your server falls back to `index.html`. You're using that behaviour because you always want to serve the same page and your JavaScript will decide what it should render.

Similarly to how you always request `/bundle.js`, you also want to request `/styles.css` regardless of the actual URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

This issue only appears in your production build, because you are using `style-loader` in development, which injects the CSS into a `<style>` tag from your JavaScript.

Comment: Well that makes complete sense, but I had only just put that in there ... to see if that changes anything. You can also see that it is actually commented out right now in my HTML file, and wasn't originally there.

Comment: It's not commented out, it's on line 3.

Comment: I don't know what line 3 is cause that is not in my current Head tag ... i show you in the answer above

Comment: just posted it up, but I will say I didn't even notice line 3 in that network response ... that is interesting.

Comment: Whatever HTML you're serving as a fallback does contain that line. Make sure your server uses the correct HTML file.

Comment: Thanks! I think this helped me pinpoint the issue, and I got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this - in case of CSS not working on refresh or hard reload

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/css/style.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```